# Running Spark in Memory-constrained Settings

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am interested in any tips/tricks or configuration options for running Spark in very memory-constrained environments. What are the most important considerations for deployments with small available memory?

Answer (score 3):

Good data processing fundamentals will get you very far.

- Avoid dragging around columns you don't need.
- Use memory efficient types like int instead of strings.
- Avoid operations that require materializing large sets of data in memory such as joins, sorts and group bys.
- Consider breaking your queries down into multiple smaller queries.  For example running your query on hourly sets of data instead of daily.
- Ensure you have a reasonable number of partitions so that the amount of data per partition is low.
- Make sure you are correctly handling skew. this can cause the memory utilization of a single task to sky rocket.
- Run more cpus per executor to get a larger pool of memory to share between tasks.
- Make sure you have  sane ratio of memory to CPUs.  You may even want to leave some cpus under utilized and dedicate more memory per task.
- Lastly you can also utilize a fast disk when you do run out of memory.  Spark has the ability to spill to disk when doing sorts, and joins.